# How does SuppressMessageAttribute work?

Tags: c#, attributes

Could you explain me how does `SuppressMessageAttribute` work? According to this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) I gave an opinion that it does something with final assembly.

Let's suppose that we have the following method:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1804:RemoveUnusedLocals", MessageId = "myUnusedLocalIntVariable")]
        public override string ToString()
        {
            int myUnusedLocalIntVariable = 5;

            return String.Format($"Name: {Name}, age: {Age.ToString()}.");
        }
```

I expect that this attribute will remove my unused local variable from the final assembly. So I looked at the assembly by using `ildasm`. But I found my unused local variable. And now I don't know how it works? Could you give me the simplest example where it could be used?

Comment: When code analysis tool inspects your assembly - it will see this attribute and not produce given message if it otherwise would. It will not change anything in your assembly - code analysis is for pure informational purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (as the name suggests) just informs the compiler not to show a warning
It can't modify your code

If you compile your in release mode *a* compiler *might* remove it if it is smart enough or the JIT compiler will probably do it in runtime.
In any case, the attribute doesn't affect this at all